# How to fix problem with DeadObjectException?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, ddms

I have successfully finished an Android project's implementation and started to test the app for memory leaks.

Sometimes, I get `DeadObjectException`after a long trip in the app and all of the memory allocations are freed.

How can I detect this problem?

I have made some research about DDMS tools to detect memory leaks, Due to I have no idea about `DeadObjectExeption`, I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 37):

This is not a memory leak problem. Definition of the memory leak (from Wikipedia):

> A memory leak, in computer science (or leakage, in this context),
>   occurs when a computer program acquires memory but fails to release it
>   back to the operating system.

Here, you have an opposite case - memory is freed before it should (at least from your program's point of view).

From developer.android.com:

> **DeadObjectException** extends RemoteException
>
> **The object you are calling has died, because its hosting process no longer exists.**

For example:

You have the classes `MyActivity` and `MyService`. You use `Handler`/`Messenger` to communicate between them.

You create `Handler` and `Messenger` in `MyActivity`, and then send created instance of `Messenger` to `MyService` via an `Intent`. Then you do some stuff, time passes, and your `MyActivity` gets destroyed, together with it's `Handler` and `Messenger`. Now, if you don't handle that well, `MyService` won't know that `Messenger` that he has is not valid any more, so, he tries to send something through it, and get `DeadObjectexception`:

> /*
>   Send a Message to this Messenger's Handler.
>
> Parameters:
>
> message The Message to send. Usually retrieved through Message.obtain().
>
> Throws:
>
> RemoteException **Throws DeadObjectException if the target Handler no longer exists.***/
>
> public void send(Message message) throws RemoteException {...}

Comment: In android, I know it'll happen between my app main process and sub process. How about when it happens between a thread and another thread in the same process?

Comment: how to prevent crashes ? please suggest for it.

Answer (score 0):

If You are calling any function from Native Library(.so file), Just check the package name used while creating JNI function is same as you are declaring native method in Java class.