# Android activity crash (DeadObjectException)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-native-library

Here is my logcat details. Please help me out in this:

```
03-28 11:58:13.421     992-5910/? D/ActivityManager﹕ New dropbox entry: com.dpc.selfie, data_app_native_crash, 5f2d762f-9b90-42d2-8a2a-bda978da87bc
03-28 11:58:13.431     992-5910/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Force finishing activity com.dpc.selfie/.Act.Activity_Feeds
03-28 11:58:13.461     992-1177/? W/InputDispatcher﹕ channel '4443fea0 com.dpc.selfie/com.dpc.selfie.Act.Activity_Feeds (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0xd
03-28 11:58:13.461     992-1177/? E/InputDispatcher﹕ channel '4443fea0 com.dpc.selfie/com.dpc.selfie.Act.Activity_Feeds (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
03-28 11:58:13.501      310-310/? D/Zygote﹕ Process 5738 terminated by signal (7)
03-28 11:58:13.531     992-5910/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3663K, 18% free 44731K/54304K, paused 91ms, total 91ms
03-28 11:58:13.531     992-1003/? W/InputDispatcher﹕ Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '4443fea0 com.dpc.selfie/com.dpc.selfie.Act.Activity_Feeds (server)'
03-28 11:58:13.531     992-1003/? I/WindowState﹕ WIN DEATH: Window{4443fea0 u0 com.dpc.selfie/com.dpc.selfie.Act.Activity_Feeds}
03-28 11:58:13.541     992-5910/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Exception thrown during pause
    android.os.DeadObjectException
            at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
            at android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy.schedulePauseActivity(ApplicationThreadNative.java:665)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startPausingLocked(ActivityStack.java:766)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:2465)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishTopRunningActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:2342)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.finishTopRunningActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2075)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleAppCrashLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:9607)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.makeAppCrashingLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:9500)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.crashApplication(ActivityManagerService.java:10197)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleApplicationCrashInner(ActivityManagerService.java:9696)
            at com.android.server.am.NativeCrashListener$NativeCrashReporter.run(NativeCrashListener.java:86)
03-28 11:58:13.551     992-4187/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Process com.dpc.selfie (pid 5738) has died.
03-28 11:58:13.561    1517-1517/? D/CustomizationProcess﹕ dismissCustomizationDialog:true
03-28 11:58:13.641    5328-5922/? I/CrashMonitor﹕ CrashMonitorServiceBroadcastReceiver: Forwarding intent: android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED tag: SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE
03-28 11:58:13.641    5328-5328/? I/CrashMonitor﹕ CrashMonitorService: Service started...`
```

I am also getting this exception when I start scrolling the RecyclerView. I am loading images in this RecyclerView view. Any solution is appreciated.

Here is the updated crash report:

```
04-04 15:32:34.796  30992-30992/? I/DEBUG﹕ pid: 13550, tid: 13550, name: com.dpc.selfie  >>> com.dpc.selfie <<<
04-04 15:32:36.226    635-15124/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Force finishing activity com.dpc.selfie/.Act.Activity_Feeds
04-04 15:32:37.726      635-941/? I/WindowState﹕ WIN DEATH: Window{4285a578 u0 com.dpc.selfie/com.dpc.selfie.Act.Activity_Feeds}
04-04 15:32:37.726    635-18714/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Process com.dpc.selfie (pid 13550) (adj 0) has died.
04-04 15:32:37.866      635-635/? D/CrashAnrDetector﹕ Build: samsung/young2ds2gdd/young2ds2g:4.4.2/KOT49H/G130EXXU0ANL1:user/release-keys
    Hardware: SC6815AS
    Revision: 0
    Bootloader: unknown
    Radio: unknown
    Kernel: Linux version 3.10.17-3684765 (dpi@SWDD6212) (gcc version 4.7 (GCC) ) #2 PREEMPT Mon Dec 29 20:48:36 KST 2014
    *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
    Build fingerprint: 'samsung/young2ds2gdd/young2ds2g:4.4.2/KOT49H/G130EXXU0ANL1:user/release-keys'
    Revision: '0'
    pid: 13550, tid: 13550, name: com.dpc.selfie  >>> com.dpc.selfie <<<
    signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000008
    r0 00000008  r1 00000000  r2 00000004  r3 00000008
    r4 57502ea8  r5 574dc378  r6 be991004  r7 00000000
    r8 56cab794  r9 ffffffff  sl 0000a93e  fp be9913bc
    ip 4063fbc4  sp be990fa0  lr 4051ace9  pc 400fb3f4  cpsr 000e0010
    d0  3f800000437f0000  d1  0000000000000000
    d2  0000000000000000  d3  0000000000000000
    d4  0000000000000000  d5  0000000000000000
    d6  0000000000000000  d7  437f00003f800000
    d8  0000000000000000  d9  41b0000041b00000
    d10 4230000042300000  d11 3ff0000000000000
    d12 406fe00000000005  d13 3ff0000000000000
    d14 3fe1c71c71c71c72  d15 3ffccccccccccccd
    d16 0000000000000001  d17 0000000000000000
    d18 0000000000000000  d19 0000000000ef8000
    d20 7027e00000ef8000  d21 0004000000000000
    d22 2004000000000000  d23 6000000000000000
    d24 0000000000000001  d25 0000000020000000
    d26 0000000020000001  d27 0000000000000000
    d28 4014000000000000  d29 0000000000000000
    d30 3ff0000000000000  d31 3f8acbd7ed95e70c
    scr 68000013
    backtrace:
    #00  pc 000033f4  /system/lib/libcutils.so (android_atomic_inc+4)
    #01  pc 0008fce5  /system/lib/libskia.so (SkBitmap::updatePixelsFromRef() const+30)
    #02  pc 0002b171  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #03  pc 0002b7e1  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #04  pc 00029d41  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #05  pc 0001e2bf  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #06  pc 0001f7b1  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #07  pc 0001fa6f  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #08  pc 00021005  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #09  pc 00016e91  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #10  pc 000146ed  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #11  pc 000145db  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #12  pc 0001d335  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #13  pc 0006bdd9  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
    #14  pc 0001dd4c  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
    #15  pc 0004dfc7  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+394)
    #16  pc 00027160  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    #17  pc 0002e0a8  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
    #18  pc 0002b754  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
    #19  pc 0006069d  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInvokeMethod(Object*, Method const*, ArrayObject*, ArrayObject*, ClassObject*, bool)+392)
    #20  pc 000685b3  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    #21  pc 00027160  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    #22  pc 0002e0a8  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
    #23  pc 0002b754  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
    #24  pc 000603bb  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+338)
    #25  pc 00049c17  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    #26  pc 00051a1f  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
    #27  pc 00052fb3  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, char const*)+354)
    #28  pc 0000105b  /system/bin/app_process
    #29  pc 0000e42b  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+50)
    #30  pc 00000d7c  /system/bin/app_process
    stack:
    be990f60  5751e348
    be990f64  40118f0d  /system/lib/libc.so (dlmalloc+4244)
    be990f68  00000498
    be990f6c  40151e00  /system/lib/libc.so
    be990f70  40117e79  /system/lib/libc.so (dlmalloc)
    be990f74  be99107c  [stack]
    be990f78  00000000
    be990f7c  be991120  [stack]
    be990f80  be990f9c  [stack]
    be990f84  574dc378
    be990f88  be991004  [stack]
    be990f
04-04 15:32:37.866      635-635/? D/CrashAnrDetector﹕ processName:com.dpc.selfie
04-04 15:32:37.866      635-635/? D/CrashAnrDetector﹕ broadcastEvent : com.dpc.selfie SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE
```

Comment: show activity code too

Comment: This link May help you :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21826670/deadobjectexception-on-android-app

Comment: I am not able to figure out what wrong am doing.Everything is fine in sony phones but in some other brands i am not able to scroll itself and moreover am not using any service in my app. And i am getting this also,532-3005/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Force finishing activity.
Please help me out in this, i am struckup with this thing, not able to go further.

Comment: I have updated the crash report, please have a look over it and help me

Comment: Finally it is working fine just by a line of code in manifest file, here it is

**`android:hardwareAccelerated="false"`** 

If anybody get the following kind of errors please try by adding the above line

_`signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR)`_

Answer (score 9):

This exception is caused when you are interacting with a remote process and the remote process was previously killed.  I saw it a lot when doing keyboards because the app would try to access our keyboard after it crashed.  Here it looks like an activity finished and tried to return to the previous activity, which was already dead.  It can probably be safely caught most of the time.  But the real solution is to fix the initial crash.  You can't have a dead object if the first object doesn't die.

Comment: what do you mean by "remote process"? I'm having this issue in my app and I can't seem to resolve it or find where the issue is happening.

Answer (score 0):

**DeadObjectException extends RemoteException**

This Exception means , The object you are calling has died, because its hosting process no longer exists. And check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7037093/android-dead-object-exception) for your reference based on DeadObjectException.

Answer (score 0):

This crash can also happen on AdMob ads (WebViews), when doing frequent orientation changes whilst the ad is loading.

For example, you will see the native C++ crash in webview.apk:

```
A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x4 in tid 21697
A/DEBUG: backtrace:
A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 00d12b44  /system/app/webview/webview.apk (offset 0x7ea000)
```

followed by the Java crash:

```
android.os.DeadObjectException
```

One solution is to install or update the '[Android System WebView](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.webview)' app from the Google Play Store. More info here: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/Q-edauZ27g8/discussion