# Crash caused by com.android.chrome

Tags: android, admob, android-webview

I'm getting this caused by `com.android.chrome`. I think this is coming from AdMob ads, since that is the only usage of WebViews in my app.

## Partial Crashlog

```
2019-03-06 13:46:29.236 17091-17091/au.com.mydomain.app A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0 in tid 17091 (.mydomain.app), pid 17091 (.mydomain.app)
2019-03-06 13:46:29.314 17421-17421/? I/crash_dump64: obtaining output fd from tombstoned, type: kDebuggerdTombstone
2019-03-06 13:46:29.314 892-892/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: received crash request for pid 17091
2019-03-06 13:46:29.315 17421-17421/? I/crash_dump64: performing dump of process 17091 (target tid = 17091)
2019-03-06 13:46:29.323 17421-17421/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
2019-03-06 13:46:29.323 17421-17421/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'google/blueline/blueline:9/PQ2A.190205.001/5163636:user/release-keys'
2019-03-06 13:46:29.323 17421-17421/? A/DEBUG: Revision: 'MP1.0'
2019-03-06 13:46:29.323 17421-17421/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm64'
2019-03-06 13:46:29.323 17421-17421/? A/DEBUG: pid: 17091, tid: 17091, name: .mydomain.app  >>> au.com.mydomain.app <<<
2019-03-06 13:46:29.323 17421-17421/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0
2019-03-06 13:46:29.323 17421-17421/? A/DEBUG: Cause: null pointer dereference
2019-03-06 13:46:29.323 17421-17421/? A/DEBUG:     x0  0000000000000000  x1  0000007ff9c0d1e8  x2  0000000000000002  x3  0000000000000013
2019-03-06 13:46:29.323 17421-17421/? A/DEBUG:     x4  0000007cabd63ef0  x5  0000000000000009  x6  0000000000000000  x7  00000000000042c3
2019-03-06 13:46:29.323 17421-17421/? A/DEBUG:     x8  0000000000000000  x9  0000000000000000  x10 0000000000000000  x11 0000000000000000
2019-03-06 13:46:29.323 17421-17421/? A/DEBUG:     x12 0000000002ec1fc0  x13 00000000341555ad  x14 0000000000000018  x15 000002cb2c562cd4
2019-03-06 13:46:29.323 17421-17421/? A/DEBUG:     x16 0000007caf04c0b8  x17 0000007d44047184  x18 000000005c7f3485  x19 0000007caa1a5300
2019-03-06 13:46:29.323 17421-17421/? A/DEBUG:     x20 0000000000000001  x21 0000000000000013  x22 0000000000000002  x23 0000007c915ff970
2019-03-06 13:46:29.323 17421-17421/? A/DEBUG:     x24 0000000000000000  x25 0000000000000000  x26 0000007ca9d425e0  x27 0000007caa1a5300
2019-03-06 13:46:29.323 17421-17421/? A/DEBUG:     x28 0000007c915ff9a0  x29 0000007ff9c0d190
2019-03-06 13:46:29.323 17421-17421/? A/DEBUG:     sp  0000007ff9c0d160  lr  0000007cadb06b00  pc  0000007cadd47620
2019-03-06 13:46:29.347 17421-17421/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
2019-03-06 13:46:29.3
```

[Full Crashlog](https://gist.github.com/drspaceboo/bcb149bdc34ca30b379f33072a8b3c29)

Comment: Does your app contain any native code, or is it pure Java (or other JVM languages)?

Comment: @JosephSible It has some native code. However I cannot trace the crashes back to it.

Answer (score 1):

This crash can also happen on AdMob ads (WebViews), when doing frequent orientation changes whilst the ad is loading.
ollowed by the Java crash:

android.os.DeadObjectException
One solution is to install or update the '[[Android System WebView]](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.webview)' app from the Google

see this 
[Android activity crash (DeadObjectException)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29314489/android-activity-crash-deadobjectexception)